# AWS SNS can't use createPlatformEndpoint

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have some problems adding devices to a AWS SNS topic and maybe someone can help me.

```
    let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
        let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
        request.token = deviceTokenString
        request.customUserData = "XXXXXXXX"
        request.platformApplicationArn = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWithBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                if task.error != nil {
                    println("Error: \(task.error)")
                } else {
                    let createEndpointResponse = task.result as AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
                    println("endpointArn: \(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn)")
                }

                return nil
            })
```

I've got an error using this code:
"Cannot invoke 'continueWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject!)'

And i don't know how to solve it.

I've included these frameworks in my Obj-C_bridging file:

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>
#import <AWSSQS/AWSSQS.h>
#import <AWSSNS/AWSSNS.h>
#import <AWSCognito/AWSCognito.h>
#import <Bolts/BFTask.h>
```

I don't know what else i can try :S Hope anyone can help, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.2.x? The Bolts dependency was removed in 2.2.0, and you need to update

```
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWithBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
```

to

```
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWithBlock({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
```

See our [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx31LFFH2WPO706/AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-iOS-2-2-0) for more details.

Comment: I know it was removed, i was trying random things to solve my problem, but you've saved me, cause this is correct :D But then there's a mistake in amazon's AWS website, cause they are using BFTask instead of AWSTask. Hope this question will help further users. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: We updated [iOS Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/) when we released AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.2.0. Could you let me know where you found a reference to `BFTask` on our website? We'll update them as well. Thanks.